# Trying to extend Abstractsequentiallist in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to extend the AbstractSequentialList class in Java.  The class implements an interface that requires the creation of a ListIterator method.  I've created the method below to simply get started but I am getting warning messages saying:

```
ListIterator is a raw type. References to generic type ListIterator<E> should be parameterized.
```

What does this mean?  I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this is giving me an erro as I run this code..

```
public ListIterator listIterator(int i){

        ListIterator listiterator = this.listIterator();

        return listiterator;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AbstractSequentialList` is generic, and so should be the ListIterator it returns. This will ensure the type safety of operations done using that iterator. Make sure your subclass is generic (`MyAbstractSequentialList<T>`), and change your code to:

```
public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int i){

        ListIterator<E> listiterator = this.listIterator();

        return listiterator;
}
```

You can take a look at Java's `LinkedList`'s source code, it extends `AbstractSequentialList`.

You can also make your class non-generic, but then you'll have to extend a concrete type of `AbstractSequentialList` (i.e. with a specified type argument). On that case, replace the `E`s in the code above with that type as well.

Comment: I think I got it, though I cannot simply say <E>, I need to actually list the object that I am iterating over, correct?  My list will contain a collection of widgets, so <widget> is what I should place after ListIterator, correct?

Comment: @WildBill, that is correct if your list extends `AbstractSequentialList<Widget>` (which is the case I refer to in my last paragraph).